# Can I yield from an inner function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, generator, yield, ecmascript-6

With ES6 generators, I see code like this:

```
var trivialGenerator = function *(array) {
    var i,item;
    for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        item = array[i];
        yield item;
    };
};
```

Is it possible to write something more like the code below instead?

```
var trivialGenerator = function *(array) {
    array.forEach(function *(item){
        yield item;
    });
};
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. you simply regenerate the input array. In any case, the answer is no. In your case though you could use a for..of loop.

Comment: I don't think it is possible... a classic for loop stmt will be the right fit

Comment: The classic for loop is by no means an abomination. In fact, as you are seeing, in part because of generators it is making a comeback.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, you can't use [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) inside of the inner function. But in your case you don't need it. You can always use [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. It will look much prettier, and you can use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue), [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) inside it:

```
var trivialGenerator = function *(array) {
    for (var item of array) {
        // some item manipulation
        yield item;
    }
}
```

You can use `for-of` if you have some manipulations with item inside it. Otherwise you absolutely don't need to create this generator, as `array` has [`iterator` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol) natively.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't yield from a callback (technically, it's not an "inner function", which means something else). There's obviously no way to call `forEach` with the equivalent of `*`, or, if the callback itself is a generator, to tell `forEach` to invoke the callback with `yield *`.

One alternative is to write a function `forEachGen`, as follows:

```
function *forEachGen(array, fn) { for (var i of array) yield *fn(i); }
```

essentially moving the for-loop into `forEachGen`. Defining a little sample generator as

```
function *yieldSelf(item) { yield item; }
```

`forEachGen` would be used as

```
yield *forEachGen(array, yieldSelf);
```

This assumes the callback is a generator itself, as you seem to imply you want in your example. If the callback were a ROF (regular old function), such as

```
function returnSelf(item) { return item; }
```

Then it would be

```
function *forEachGen(array, fn) { for (var i of array) yield fn(i); }
```

used as

```
yield *forEachGen(array, returnSelf);
```

If you don't mind adding this to the array prototype, then

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachGen', { value :
    function *(fn) { for (i of this) yield fn(i); }
});
```

then do

```
yield *array.forEachGen(yieldSelf)
```

You may be interested in http://fitzgen.github.io/wu.js/, which defines a wrapper for generators with methods such as `forEach` on the wrapper.

#### `async` / `await`

With `await`, you should be able to do the following.

Define a trivial callback which just returns a promise for itself.

```
async function returnSelf(item) { return await item; }
```

`forEachAsync` maps the input array into an array of promises, and uses `await *` to create and return a promise for all the individual promises being ready.

```
async function forEachAsync(values, fn) {
  return await *values.map(returnSelf);
}
```

We can treat the result as a regular promise and print it out in a `then`:

```
forEachAsync([1,2,3], returnSelf) .
  then(result => console.log(result);
```

or use a little IIFE async wrapper to do wait for the result and then print it out:

```
(async function() { 
    console.log(await forEachAsync([1,2,3], returnSelf));
})();
```

Tested using

```
babel-node --experimental test.js
```

Comment: As I defined it, I think it **is** non-iterable, or do you mean non-enumerable, or did I miss something? Default for `enumerable` is `false`.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but I cannot move the for-loop into `forEachGen` as in my case it's not an array, it's a stream where I'm getting my items from.
So far, the only solution I could think of is to buffer the items and then iterate over them with a generator function. But this heavily breaks the "infinite nature" of streams and will reduce throughput. Do you have any idea on how to deal with something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't but you can create your own wrapper to convert the function into a generator. Here's how I did it:

```
export async function* createListFilesIterator(
  worker: DriveWorker,
): AsyncGenerator<FilesResp, void, unknown> {
  const messages: FilesResp[] = [];
  let processed = 0;
  let waited = 0;
  let done = false;

  worker.onmessage = (msg) => {
    const { data: evt } = msg;
    if (evt.type === "files") {
      messages.push(evt);
    } else if (evt.type === "done") {
      done = true;
    }
  };

  while (processed < messages.length || (!done && waited <= 16)) {
    if (processed < messages.length) {
      yield messages[processed];
      waited = 0;
      processed += 1;
    } else {
      waited += 1;
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000 * waited * 0.5);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

With this method I can convert my worker instance into an iterator which I can loop through with:

```
for await (const evt of createListFilesIterator(worker)) {
   ...
```

Of course I could make it a lot more simpler by just returning a promise with an onmessage eventlistener inside of it but I just wanted to see whether this was doable / made sense. I think when you grow beyond two return types generators become much cleaner and easier to use than event listeners. But that's my opinion, for certain.